# What is the hidden character causing JSON.parse to fail?

Tags: regex, json, character

I am using JSON.parse in JavaScript to parse some JSON. It ha sa problem if I copy the text from [this example](http://www.jquery4u.com/json/iphone-menu-json-example/). I double click to copy the text to my clipboard. If I strip out all whitespace using a regex, it works. But I can't find the offending character. I've tried:

```
replace(/\t/g,'');
replace(/\n/g,'');
replace(/\r/g,'');
replace(/\0/g,'');
replace(/\x0B/g,'');
```

...and still the offending character remains. What can I do to track it down. If I paste the text into Notepad in Windows, the character is removed and JSON.parse works.

Comment: i don't get it, are you trying to parse it from your clipboard? When you copy it, where are you pasting it to consume it from js?

Answer (score 1):

When I copy-and-paste it, the indentation consists of NO-BREAK SPACE characters, code 0x80, which is encoded in UTF-8 as the sequence 0xc2, 0xa0

When I replace all the NO-BREAK SPACE characters by ordinary spaces (0x20), I'm able to parse it as JSON (using Perl's `JSON::decode_json`).

Comment: I'm trying this but it isn't working:

`replace(/\0xc2|0xa0\g/,' ');`

Comment: @Jack: I don't know JavaScript well enough to figure out why that doesn't work.

Comment: `.replace(/\0x20|\0x0A\g/,' ');` worked for me. '0xc2' should have been '0x20'. I downloaded a hex editor to find the characters I needed to replace.

Comment: @Jack: 0x20 is the ordinary space character, which is valid; you shouldn't need to delete it.  And 0x0A is ASCII LF, the end-of-line marker, also valid in JSON.  Something odd is happening.

Comment: The offending characters show as `CA` in a hex editor, and '        ' in plain text. Calling `JSON.parse('        ');` causes the SyntaxError.